# Parse file using python - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bed file :

```
chr         start   stop   strand   count
chr1        0       13320   -       1
chr1        13320   13321   -       2
chr1        13321   13328   -       1
chr1        13328   13342   -       2
chr1        13342   13343   -       18
chr1        13343   13344   -       36
chr1        13344   13345   -       18
chr1        13345   13346   -       6
chr1        13346   16923   -       1
chr1        16923   16942   -       3
chr1        16942   16943   -       2
```

and I would like to filter out position where count=1, combines overlapping positions in the interval between the position where count=1 and output the median of counts.

Expected output in that case :

```
chr1        13320   13321    2
chr1        13328   13346   18
chr1        16923   16943   2.5
```

I wrote the following script that did the job :

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
file = Path("bed_file.bed")
# load with pandas
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None)

# set colnames
header = ['chr','start','stop','strand','count']
df.columns = header[:len(df.columns)]

# index where count=1
col_count = df['count'].tolist()
li = [i for i, n in enumerate(col_count) if n == 1]

# create new dataframe
newDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['chr','start', 'stop', 'count'])
# last position
end = df.index[-1]

# parse dataframe
for idx, elem in enumerate(li):
    if elem != li[-1]: 
        next_elem = li[(idx + 1) % len(li)] # next element where count=1
        start = df.iloc[elem]['stop'] # start position 
        stop = df.iloc[next_elem-1]['stop'] # stop position
        if next_elem - (elem+1) == 1: # cases where only one position and we cannot compute median
            count = df.iloc[elem+1]['count']
            #print(f"start={start}\tstop={stop}\tcount={count}")
        else:
            count = df.iloc[elem+1:next_elem]['count'].median()
            #print(f"start={start}\tstop={stop}\tcount={count}")
        newDF = newDF.append({
            'chr' : df.loc[0,'chr'],
            'start' : start,
            'stop' : stop,
            'count' : count
            
        },ignore_index=True)
    else: # last element in the list
        start = df.iloc[elem]['stop']
        stop = df.iloc[end]['stop']
        count = df.iloc[elem+1:end+1]['count'].median()
        #print(f"start={start}\tstop={stop}\tcount={count}")
        newDF = newDF.append({
            'chr' : df.loc[0,'chr'],
            'start' : start,
            'stop' : stop,
            'count' : count
        },ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a best way to do it ? Is this script pythonic ?!
I would like to improve my python coding skills :)
Thanks in advance !

Comment: can't you do `df.columns = ['chr','start','stop','strand','count']` ?

Comment: you don't need `Path` - `read_csv("bed_file.bed", ...)`

Comment: `pandas` should have function to drop rows and you don't have to convert `to_list` and use list comprehension - `df = df[ df['count'] != 1 ]`

Comment: if code is working then it is not place for you question but you should ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @furas I idid'nt know the code review website. Thx for the information.